# Excel IF and AND with 4 outputs

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm trying yo update an IF function but get an error highlighting "E41"

I have the following which works fine:

```
=IF(AND(E41<B9,(B9-E41)<=E36,E31>=B9),"Yes, remaining d is sufficient",IF(E31<B9,"d limits DF range",IF(E41>=B9,"L not limiting DF range")))
```

The new 4th condition is added below but gives an error:

(the text within the " and " is different but this isn't the cause of the problem!)

```
=IF(AND(E41<B9,(B9-E41)<=E36,E31>=B9),"Yes, remaining d is sufficient",IF(E31<B9,"d limits DF range",IF(E41>=B9,"L not limiting DF range")),IF(B9-E41)>E36,"Insufficient d after L runs out"))
```

My four cases and the conditions are therefore:

```
If E31<B9 - display "d limits DF range"

If E41>B9 - display "L not limiting DF range"

If E41<B9 and (B9-E41)=<E36 and E31 >=B9 - display "Yes remainging d is sufficient"
```

New condition is to take into account extra option of

```
If E41<B9 and (B9-E41)>E36 then display "insufficient d once L runs out"
```

Any help most gratefully received! Trying to get the syntax understood still!

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

## Multiple Conditions Excel Formula

```
=IF(AND(E41<B9,B9-E41<=E36,E31>=B9),"Yes, remaining d is sufficient",IF(E31<B9,"d limits DF range",IF(E41>=B9,"L not limiting DF range",IF(B9-E41>E36,"Insufficient d after L runs out"))))
```

---

### Compare

```
=IF(AND(E41<B9,B9-E41<=E36,E31>=B9),"Yes, remaining d is sufficient",IF(E31<B9,"d limits DF range",IF(E41>=B9,"L not limiting DF range",IF(B9-E41>E36,"Insufficient d after L runs out"))))
=IF(AND(E41<B9,(B9-E41)<=E36,E31>=B9),"Yes, remaining d is sufficient",IF(E31<B9,"d limits DF range",IF(E41>=B9,"L not limiting DF range")),IF(B9-E41)>E36,"Insufficient d after L runs out"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=IF(AND(E41=B9),"Yes, remaining d is sufficient",IF(E31=B9,"L not limiting DF range",IF(B9-E41)>E36,"Insufficient d after L runs out","None is True"))))`

Cheers 
Tim